# Fast conversion of date/time string to boost::posix_time::ptime (C++ Windows Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2022

I have to read almost a million records from a text file that contain a date/time strings of the format  "Tue Jan 30 15:28:47 CET 2024".

So far I'm using the code below, but this appears to be a major performance sink as the profiler says it consumes most of the processing power. (Which isn't surprising as the conversion looks very expensive.) What would be a faster way to convert this? Visual Studio 2022, C++ and boost.

```
boost::posix_time::ptime result;
const std::locale timeFormat = std::locale(std::locale::classic(), new boost::posix_time::time_input_facet("%a %b %d %H %M %S CET %YYYY"));
std::istringstream is(timestamp);
is.imbue(timeFormat);
is >> result;
```

Comment: Just to be clear: You're creating a million `istringstream`s and imbuing each of them with a custom `timeFormat` ?

Comment: What version of C++ can you use? Have a look at the chrono header and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/from_stream functionality. However if you have control over the input files try (to add) a different time format (e.g. seconds since begin of epoch). If you have that many entries design at the system level also becomes important, not trying to just locally work around the problem.

Comment: Yes, I expected more like 10k messages for which this expensive method wouldn't have been an issue. Turns out there are a LOT more.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over the file format :( That comes from an external process that I can't change. But the format is fixed so I could juggle the strings before converting them. 
I'll check out std::chrono::from_stream, thanks.

Comment: If you give an example of the input file, and more importantly describe the use-case (which allows us to justify conversion to ptime in the first place, or maybe whether some other  (intermediate) representation is more efficient) I'd like to create a sample benchmark

Comment: The use case behind that is complex and I'm not sure what a description would accomplish. 
The input file is a message stream, a header with a time stamp, and a second part depending on the message type. (Which basically comes from a Kafka system that we have no control over.) All messages are parsed, and then data is collated as we derive information from several messages. For this naturally we need the timestamp because there are time dependencies and hysteresis describing which messages belong together and which don't.

Comment: Here is a list of the IANA time zones that use the abbreviation "CET" on the date time referenced:  
Africa/Algiers
Africa/Ceuta
Africa/Tunis
CET
Europe/Andorra
Europe/Belgrade
Europe/Berlin
Europe/Brussels
Europe/Budapest
Europe/Gibraltar
Europe/Madrid
Europe/Malta
Europe/Paris
Europe/Prague
Europe/Rome
Europe/Tirane
Europe/Vienna
Europe/Warsaw
Europe/Zurich
Can you assume one of these time zones?  Or at least exclude some?  If not, mapping the local time to UTC will not be possible.  And temporally grouping messages in local time across DST boundaries will be challenging.

Comment: Yes, we know the timezone as the data is generated in a fixed city. Not sure if that is daylight saving time, but that can be worked around later if necessary.